# Is it 'garment' or 'garments' when referring to trousers/pants?

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural, nouns, plural-forms

For example, when referring to a single pair of trousers/pants worn by one person as "the tight-fitting garment(s)", is garment pluralized since the words trousers and pants are, or is it singular since the sentence is only referring to one pair of trousers/pants?

Comment: *Trousers* and *pants* are a kind of word we call **plurale tantum**, words that only ever appear plural, but *garment* isn't like that.  So yes, it's "pants are a garment."  Confusing, but that's the way it is!

Comment: Very tricky: they're singular at the top and plural at the bottom ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/garment) says

> **garment**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> An item of clothing.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/trousers) also says

> **trousers**
> <sub>PLURAL NOUN</sub>
>
> An outer **garment** covering the body from the waist to the ankles, with a separate part for each leg.

which shows the singular use of 'garment' for one pair of trousers.

---

Similarly for other plural nouns:

> These scissors are a useful kitchen tool.

They are one tool, but with an apparent contradiction between *are* and the singular *a*.